# Change initialisation variable

Tags: c, mplab

Im working on something that when turned on for the first time ever I want it to use a default variable but once this is changed I want it to start up with the new variable. Once I disconnect power and start it up again, the value is restored to 9. How do I change it so it saves forever, so basically it'll start up the first time with the initialisation value but from then on, even after power has been turned off, it'll remember the changed value and start up with that one instead?

Using mplab and coding in C

Heres a very basic example, although it will jump to the while loop and set it to 20 the first time, I want it to remember it was set to 20 when it restarts after the power is turned off:

```
void main (void)
{
    M1sps = 9; // start up with this value

    while(1)
    {
        if (M1sps == 9) // if M1sps is 9, change to 20.
        {
            M1sps = 20; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the type when declaring a variable. `int M1sps = 9;`

Comment: If you want something saved permanently, you have to write it to a file.

Comment: In a microcontroller, you probably use NVRAM.

Comment: If the file can be opened, read the value. If it can't, use the default value and create the file.

Comment: Sorry yes, I forgot the int on that variable. My bad.

Comment: I cannot use a file I don't think, I'm coding a microchip

Comment: I'll have a look at NVRAM now, thank you

Comment: Does this device have any configuration bits? Such as a few bits of flash or eeprom memory.

Comment: Yes it does, I'm using the pic16f18326

Comment: So use a bit/byte of the EEPROM, it has 256 bytes. Read the data sheet and/or user's manual to learn how to access it.

Comment: Thank you, on it now

Comment: Alternatively (maybe?) use a command-line parameter (with default = 20) to specify the initial value of the variable: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int M1sps = 20; if (argc == 2) M1sps = atoi(argv[1]); /* ... */ }`